# Conditional conversion of media

Tags: media, codec, video-conversion, audio-conversion

I have a collection of videos in various formats.  While all of them play perfectly on my computer, it's a different matter when I put them on a stick to watch on my TV.  I would like to convert them so that they are all compatible with my TV.

I'm looking for a program that can do the following:

- Take a list of compatible media formats for audio & video streams
- For each file, determine if its container, video or audio needs to be converted
- If conversion is required, extract the streams, covert as required, then re-package them in a compatible container file

Basically, if I have an AVI with compatible video but incompatible audio, I want to convert the audio but leave the video as-is.

I'm running Windows 7.

Comment: How much scripting are you willing to do?

Comment: I'm always willing.  Not always able, though :P  I should mention this is on a Windows machine.